# How to access CouchDB documents using CouchRest model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, model, couchdb, couchrest

Please help me to solve this. I’ve around 1500 documents in my CouchDB, each document belongs to any one of the types (‘**Survey**’ and ’**Response**’).

I need solution for followings

1] Need to display Document Ids (_id) in a Dropdown list which has document type (documentType) as ‘Survey’

2] If I select an item (_id) from drop down, I need to display all document Ids (_id) in list box which belongs to selected ID (_id selected from drop down list)

I've total 1500 documents like this

```
{
   "_id": "ff2fb2554682ba613c2f83c63502808a",
   "_rev": "4-dd559696434a402739e789ccc8c9a481",
   "answers": [
       {
           "answers": [
               "Aug 19,2011"
           ],
           "questionId": "50f3df434ae02ac7fff48c1c2bde83e4"
       },
       {
           "answers": [
               "Bechu Yadav"
           ],
           "questionId": "15504f006e58872fd94871fe0c9d32ad"
       },
       {
           "answers": [
               "35"
           ],
           "questionId": "3c447a2f5cc6ca1985ce2c81463a3c47"
       },
       {
           "answers": [
               "Male"
           ],
           "questionId": "a6df7c25602939554612ef6de762f5b9"
       },
       {
           "questionId": "2f66155965e60094f23f01af531d5af1",
           "subAnswers": [
               {
                   "questionId": "1dae2d86eef846c967254c9e369170ce"
               },
               {
                   "questionId": "40ffeb4d33dab1fe8d2d8b73c02ed13b"
               },
               {
                   "questionId": "2db1e8b6e97d5baa8935b9b31fcc9648"
               },
               {
                   "questionId": "0f8bb9f91ea8085b4ffb839ee8deabb5"
               },
               {
                   "questionId": "22a93ecb72c50ff8899f8b2937776e51"
               },
               {
                   "questionId": "e5106384790c2be745c952c4b867a0ff"
               }
           ]

           "questionId": "492cf9bd41257ea478c5222fbba06616"
       }
   ],
   "createdAt": "2011-08-19T21:05:36.486+0000",
   "createdBy": "user4",
   "documentType": "Response",
   "ipAddress": "42.110.85.67",
    "location": {
       "latitude": 26.8415613,
       "longitude": 75.8222883,
       "provider": "network"
   },
    "surveyId": "6df022f0f371752167ad4920b38e1c37",
    "published": true
}
```

And my CouchRest model looks like as follows

```
class Android < CouchRest::Model::Base
    property :description, String
    property :_id, String
    property :_rev, String
    property :documentType, String

    design do
      view :by_documentType,:map =>"function(doc){if (doc.documentType == 'Survey') {emit(doc._id);}}"
      view :by_createdBy
    end
 end
```

But when I access **by_documentType** it's returning **nil**

```
Android.find_by_documentType('Survey')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Friends!

Finally I found the Answer, I changed my Model as follows

```
require 'couchrest_model'

class Android < CouchRest::Model::Base

  property :description, String
  property :_id, String
  property :_rev, String
  property :documentType, String
  property :surveyId, String

  design do
    view :by_document_type,:map =>"function(doc) {if (doc.documentType == \"Survey\") {emit([doc._id,doc.title], 1);}}",:reduce=>"function(keys, values, rereduce) {return sum(values);}"
    view :by_surveyId,:map =>"function(doc) {emit([doc.surveyId], 1);}",:reduce=>"function(keys, values, rereduce) {return sum(values);}"
  end
end
```

And now able to call this view as required. following returns all the documents which has document type 'Survey'

```
Android.by_document_type.rows
```

And Based on Survey ID selection, I can retrieve all documents which belongs to selected survey id, as follows

```
Android.by_surveyId.key('Selected Survey ID goes here').rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Android.by_documentType.key('Survey')

Comment: I tried but It's returning a view instead of results. It's returning like this `#<CouchRest::Model::Designs::View:0x5453a78 @owner=Android, @model=Android, @query={:key=>"Survey"}, @name="by_documentType">`